# How do you address a child who cries and wants to play with everything?

Tags: teaching, crying, play-time, play

When we have dinner, our daughter will sit on her chair for 1 minute, and then she will go up to desk and start to play with plates and forks and food and ...

When we want to watch film or TV, she cries and wants to watch cartoons.

When we want to go on the Internet and turn on the computer, she cries and wants to play with the keyboard and mouse.

When somebody calls us and starts the conversation, she cries and wants to speak with the person on the phone.

Our daughter is 19 months old and speaks with 10 words; other than that, she screams or cries.

More than half of our time is spent playing games with her.

We love her and everything she says, and we listen to her and pay attention to her.

Please help us and show us solutions as to how we can have a normal life.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At that age, it is normal to spend pretty much all her waking time trying to interact with her - remember, the more interaction she has with you, your wife and others now, the faster her brain will develop, and the easier it is for her to learn social skills.

That said, be sensible about it - you don't both need to be with her, so take turns - each of you needs to be able to take a break. Sometimes a parent needs to get out of the house and away from their child - even if just for a coffee.

By 19 months you should be able to distract her, though, by giving her things to do. When you are working on the computer, give her an old keyboard or laptop to type on.

If the phone rings and she wants to talk, sometimes let her have a quick chat (eg if it is a grandparent, she may wish to say hello) so encourage her by taking turns:

> Granny says she would like to say hello to you...and now Granny wants
>   to talk with me again, so say bye bye

At dinner time, I think we had our kids in a high chair later than 19 months, to help get them used to being in one place to have a family dinner, and this was encouraged when they were older by ensuring all the other family members were round the table, so the children knew that if they went elsewhere they wouldn't have as much fun.

Comment: Our 2.5yr old is in a LeapFrog chair with a belt strap and I do not see us not using it anytime soon. He does not like being put in the chair, but once there he is ok with it.